# TensorFlow Placeholder shape using batch size bigger than 1

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, placeholder

I define two placeholders, x with shape [None,11] and y with shape [None,10]. Using **None** as first dimension I should be able to use the model with various batch sizes.

If I run in a stochastic gradient descent mode, using batch size one, everything works.

```
sess.run(train, {x: [df.values[i][0:11]], y: [df.values[i][11:]]})
```

In this case the placeholders x and y have shapes of (1,11) and (1,10).

If I run in full batch gradient descent mode, using the batch size 1000,
I get incompatible matrix operation errors.
In this case the placeholders x and y have shapes of (1000,11) and (1000,10).

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes:  [10,10] vs. [1000,10]
>
> [[Node: gradients/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/Sub_grad/Shape, gradients/Sub_grad/Shape_1)]]

Of course I can't subtract a (10,10) and a (1000,10).
But I think TensorFlow would handle that "batch sizes" for me?
Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy


## Import the Dummy Data from Excel
df = pd.read_excel("../data/DummyData.xlsx", sheetname=0, header=0, skiprows=1 )


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,11])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,10])

# layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[11,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10,1]))
prop_fn_1 = tf.matmul(x,W1) + b1
akt_fn_1 = tf.sigmoid(prop_fn_1)

# layer2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10,10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10,1]))
prop_fn_2 = tf.matmul(prop_fn_1, W2) + b2
akt_fn_2 = tf.sigmoid(prop_fn_2)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# error
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(akt_fn_2,y)))
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)
train = opt.minimize(loss)



# Train Stochastic
# Using Gradient Descent

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: [df.values[i][0:11]], y: [df.values[i][11:]]})

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print( sess.run(loss,{x: [df.values[i][0:11]], y: [df.values[i][11:]]} ))
sess.close()

print("*****************")


# Train with Max Batch Size
# Using Gradient Descent
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: df.values[:,:11], y: df.values[:,11:]})

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: df.values[:,:11], y: df.values[:,11:]}))
sess.close()
```

Comment: How should TF know how to do operation on incompatible tensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this for me?

```
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10]))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works.
Please give me insights/reasons into your dark arts.

Comment: The result of your first matrix multiplication has shape None x 10 . You want to add bias to each of the 10 values (what I specified). Instead you say that you add a matrix with shape [10,1]. Looking at how numpy works helps greatly, but the documentation seems to be down at the moment :(

Comment: Ok I see.
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1,10]))
would be equivalent as
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[10]))?

Comment: No. the idea is that if you have a Tensor with shape [5,4,3,2,1] for example, and you add a Tensor with shape [1] (scalar value), you add this value to each instance in the 5*4*3*2 instances. Sorry if I'm not explaining it really well :s